# The effect of number of variables on Intlinprog in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a MIP code in Matlab 2014a that uses Intlinprog function; It has an acceptable solution for small sizes of variables but just gives zero solution for larger sizes(It reads parameters from an excel file for large sizes) 
I dont know what is the problem?

Comment: Could you edit your question with more details and your code, along with any possible error messages you get, and the output that you are expecting to get?

Comment: Thanks! The problem has been solved! I had made a mistake in input data!